# mysql: check if values of an array exist in a DB table

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have an PHP array of numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5) and I want to check which of them are **not** in my DB table.

How can I do something like:

```
SELECT num FROM (0,1,2,3,4,5) AS num WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT id FROM sometable);
```

I'm asking about the right SQL synthax.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table sometable (num int not null);
insert into sometable values (1),(1),(4);
```

Solution:

```
create temporary table tmp (num int not null);
insert into tmp values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
select t.num from tmp t left join sometable s on t.num=s.num where s.num is null;
```

Or

```
select t.num from tmp t where t.num not in (select num from sometable);
```

Out:

```
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   5 |
+-----+
```